# Sorting Column By DateTime Value Not String Value?

Tags: c#, sorting, listview

I'm using this to sort a list view: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319401
It's working great, except when I try to sort a date column, it things 2AM comes after 10PM (since 2 is greater than 1).

```
4/7/2011 10:00:00 PM
4/7/2011 2:00:00 AM
```

This is the code I'm using:

```
var lvcs = new ListViewColumnSorter();
ListView.ListViewItemSorter = lvcs;
lvcs.Order = SortOrder.Ascending;
lvcs.SortColumn = 1; //<-Contains DateTime values in string format
ListView.Sort();
```

So how can I convert to DateTime and sort using the code above?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Look at the "Sorting Dates" section in [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996467.aspx) - you replace the Compare method.

Example Code:

```
try {
    DateTime dateX = Convert.ToDateTime(listviewX.SubItems[ColumnToSort].Text);
    DateTime dateY = Convert.ToDateTime(listviewY.SubItems[ColumnToSort].Text);
    compareResult = ObjectCompare.Compare(dateX, dateY);
}
catch {
    compareResult = ObjectCompare.Compare(listviewX.SubItems[ColumnToSort].Text, listviewY.SubItems[ColumnToSort].Text);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have done this for years, but just ran across the post..  I noticed Gary did something like it, but I never had a problem with it comparing date so never had to use the DateTime compare object.   Guess this is another option for people to chose from.

```
public int Compare(object x, object y)
{
    int compareResult;

    //added based on madmonk46's comment below.
    if (x == null || y == null)
        return 0;

    //get string values from parameters
    string xVal = ((ListViewItem)x).SubItems[ColumnToSort].Text;
    string yVal = ((ListViewItem)y).SubItems[ColumnToSort].Text;

    //check if values are int, long, double, or floats
    if (float.TryParse(xVal, out float xFloat) && float.TryParse(yVal, out float yFloat))
        compareResult = ObjectCompare.Compare(xFloat, yFloat);
    //check if values are dates
    else if (DateTime.TryParse(xVal, out DateTime xDateTime) && DateTime.TryParse(yVal, out DateTime yDateTime))
        compareResult = ObjectCompare.Compare(xDateTime, yDateTime);
    //compare as strings
    else
        compareResult = ObjectCompare.Compare(xVal, yVal);

    // Calculate correct return value based on object comparison
    if (OrderOfSort == SortOrder.Ascending)
    {
        // Ascending sort is selected, return normal result of compare operation
        return compareResult;
    }
    else if (OrderOfSort == SortOrder.Descending)
    {
        // Descending sort is selected, return negative result of compare operation
        return (-compareResult);
    }
    else
    {
        // Return '0' to indicate they are equal
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Great piece of code, thanks. But do use a guard before the if clause: `if (xVal == null || yVal == null) return 0;`

Comment: @MarceloScofanoDiniz I agree..  When I use it, it's usually required data columns..   But your right, if they are not require data columns, this would be an issue.   Modified, thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Works great, there's a small bug up at the top of the method in the guard clause you added. `if (xVal == null || yVal == null)` should be `if (x == null || y == null)`, `xVal` and `yVal` don't exist at that point.

Comment: Thanks.  That is what happens when I don't validate what I'm copying and pasting from comments.  :)

Answer (score 1):

The above example is the way to go but I thought I'd add this for the situation of multiple date columns. Holding the indices for the date column[s] also saves the overhead of DateTime.Parse().

In the ListViewColumnSorter class, create a private array of column indices matching your DateTime columns, eg:

```
 int[] RgIntDateColIndices;
```

When the ListViewColumnSorter class is constructed, pass in such an array, eg:

```
public ListViewColumnSorter(int[] datecolumns)
{
  ColumnToSort = 0;

  RgIntDateColIndices = datecolumns;

  OrderOfSort = SortOrder.None;

  // Initialize the CaseInsensitiveComparer object
  ObjectCompare = new CaseInsensitiveComparer();
}
```

Then, at Compare() time, eg:

```
 public int Compare(object x, object y)
 {
   int compareResult;
 
   string s1 = ((ListViewItem)x).SubItems[ColumnToSort].Text;
   string s2 = ((ListViewItem)y).SubItems[ColumnToSort].Text;
 
   bool SortByDate = false;
   for (int i=0; i<RgIntDateColIndices.Length; i++)
   {
     if (ColumnToSort == RgIntDateColIndices[i])
     {
       SortByDate = true;
       break;
     }
   }
 
   if (!SortByDate)
     compareResult = ObjectCompare.Compare(s1, s2);
   else
     compareResult = DateTime.Compare(DateTime.Parse(s1), DateTime.Parse(s2));
 
   // Calculate correct return value based on object comparison
   if (OrderOfSort == SortOrder.Ascending) // Ascending sort is selected, return normal result of compare operation
   {
     return compareResult;
   }
   if (OrderOfSort == SortOrder.Descending) // Descending sort is selected, return negative result of compare operation
   {
     return (-compareResult);
   }
 
   return 0; // Return '0' to indicate they are equal
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should get your items from  your listview and convert the date/time strings to DateTime objects and then call sort on those objects (having put them in a collection) and then put them back into your ListView.

Hopefully that solves your issue.

Comment: Hi, by putting them "back into [my] listview", will that mean the list will be cleared and refilled?

Answer (score 0):

above is correct because you are doing string comparison of list.

try to convert to DateTime and Create `List<DateTime>` and sort it then,

You can use `DateTime.TryParse` or ParseExact to specify you own parsing format

Answer (score 0):

The answer marked as correct here did not help me.  My app seemed to go in to an infinite loop of thrown exceptions.  To avoid using a try/catch and catching thrown exeptions, I used the following and it works perfectly:

```
DateTime dateX;
DateTime dateY;
if (
    DateTime.TryParse(listviewX.SubItems[ColumnToSort].Text, out dateX)
    && DateTime.TryParse(listviewY.SubItems[ColumnToSort].Text, out dateY)
    )
{
    compareResult = ObjectCompare.Compare(dateX, dateY);
}
else
{
    compareResult = ObjectCompare.Compare(listviewX.SubItems[ColumnToSort].Text, listviewY.SubItems[ColumnToSort].Text);
}
```

Comment: The appearance of the infinite loop is because the exceptions are process intensive.  Your solution is better.  Another way I did was to add a new property called SortType and in the comparison, switch on the type parsing the strings accordingly.